# Setting a variable python class - function

Tags: python, class, variables, members

Is there a function such that i can write but as a function?

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x;

asd = foo(2);
asd.x = 5;
print(asd.x);
```

But like:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,x):
       self.x = x;
    def someFunction(self,string,value):
        if(string == 'x'):
           self.x = value;
           print("worked");

 asd = foo(2);
 asd.x = 3; #and "worked" will be printed?
```

I tried __ set __ and __ setattr __ but i had no luck ;\

Is there a way to call a function when setting a class variable?
asd.x = 3; calls a function?

Comment: `self.x` and `asd.x` are the same thing, why do you want to differentiate between them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors

Comment: you probably need to declare an `@property`

Comment: Either use a @property, or replace `print("Worked")` with `return "Worked"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a property. The method decorated by `@property` will be used whenever you try to access the attribute `x`; the method subsequently decorated by `@x.setter` will be called whenever you try to set the value of `x`. The underlying "private" attribute `_x` is used to store the value for `x` used by both the getter and setter.

```
class foo:

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
        print("worked")

    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
```

The decorator syntax can be skipped if you want more explicit names for the getter and setter methods:

```
class foo(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
         self._x = x

    def _get_x(self):
        return self._x

    def _set_x(self, value):
        self._x = value
        print("worked")

    x = property(_get_x, _set_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For an object to handle setting of attributes on itself, use the `__setattr__` method.  It's rather tricky to debug, so don't do this unless you know what you're doing.   [Good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4772241/143880)

### source

```
class Beer(object):
    def __init__(self, adj):
        self.adj = adj

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print '\tSET',key,value
        object.__setattr__(self, key, value)  # new style (don't use __dict__)

b = Beer('tasty')
print 'BEFORE',b.adj
b.adj = 'warm'
print 'AFTER',b.adj
print b.__dict__
```

### output

```
    SET adj tasty
BEFORE tasty
    SET adj warm
AFTER warm
{'adj': 'warm'}
```